# Help It doesn't compile my program

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,I have a problem when I try compiling my program I have the files fismain.cpp , fis.h and  fis.c and when I compiled without ROS I havent a problem but when I try to integrate  in ROS  I cant compiling,There is not defined as certain functions are in the file fis. c.

- I've added in CMakelist.txt:

add_library(fis /home/magno/proyecto/fis.c)

rosbuild_add_executable(fismain src/fismain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(fismain fis)

The error is:

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/fismain
CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/src/fismain.o: In function `inicializaSistemaDifuso(char*)':
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:40: undefined reference to `returnFismatrix'
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:43: undefined reference to `fisBuildFisNode'
CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/src/fismain.o: In function `finalizaSistemaDifuso()':
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:56: undefined reference to `fisFreeMatrix'
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:57: undefined reference to `fisFreeMatrix'
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:58: undefined reference to `fisFreeMatrix'
CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/src/fismain.o: In function `presentarInformacion':
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:64: undefined reference to `fisPrintData'
CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/src/fismain.o: In function `evaluarFisOnLine':
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:73: undefined reference to `getFisOutput'
CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/src/fismain.o: In function `presentarInformacion':
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:64: undefined reference to `fisPrintData'
CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/src/fismain.o: In function `evaluarFisOnLine':
/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/src/fismain.cpp:73: undefined reference to `getFisOutput'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make[3]: *** [../bin/fismain] Error 1
make[3]: se sale del directorio «/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/build»
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fismain.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/build»
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/magno/proyecto/prueba5/build»
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

sorry for my english.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57813/help--it-doesn%27t-compile-my-program./) by [Bernardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4106/bernardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to use relative paths and use the ros package structure. Then your makefile is in the root of the package and the source files in src. Then add_library(fis src/fis.c)

You are also mixing c++ and c, that could also give problems.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0